# Proof or Counterexample:Is every open connected set $D \subset \mathbb C$ is a domain of holomorphy?

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

**Def:** An open set  $D \subset \mathbb C^n$  is called a **domain of Holomorphy** if there exists a holomorphic function $f$ on $D$ such that $f$ cannot be extended to a bigger set.

Is every non empty open set $D \subset \mathbb C$ is a domain of holomorphy?

I personally believe that this result is true but I'm unable to find a proof.Any ideas?

Comment: Can you do the disk?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes, $\sum z^{n!}$.

Comment: ANd why does that work?

Comment: $D \neq \varnothing$ is necessary. Do you know the (general) Weierstraß product theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer Fixed now.Yes I know,Can you please tell how to use that?Regards,

Comment: $D = \mathbb{C}$ is clear, so suppose $D\neq\mathbb{C}$. You take a sequence $(\zeta_n)$ in $D$ such that the set of accumulation points of the sequence is $\partial D$, and every $p\in\partial D$ is approached "from every side". You use Weierstraß' theorem to "find" a holomorphic function $f$ on $D$ with $f(\zeta_n) = 0$ for all $n$, and no other zeros. Then $f$ cannot be analytically continued across any boundary point, since each boundary point $p$ is an accumulation point of zeros of $f$ in any open subset $V\subset D$ such that $p\in \partial V$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. I think its more than a comment.If you found some time you can write it as a answer I'll be happy to accept it.Regards,

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez The reason why $\sum_n z^{n!}$ works is that the function value goes off to infinity along any radial path towards a root of unity and the roots of unity are dense on the unit circle, so the function cannot even be continuously extended to any point on the boundary of the disc. This argument clearly relies on the geometry of the disc. But is there a topological reason that doesn't depend on the geometry of the disc for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any nonempty open domain $ D\subset \mathbb C$ is a domain of holomorphy.
The proof is in two steps:

a) One proves that a holomorphically convex domain  $D\subset \mathbb C^n$ is a domain of holomorphy .
This is not difficult: see for example [Grauert-Fritzsche](https://books.google.fr/books/about/From_Holomorphic_Functions_to_Complex_Ma.html?id=pCXWJLTJ3isC&redir_esc=y), Theorem 6.5, page 81

b) One proves that for $n=1$ any domain $D\subset \mathbb C$ is holomorphically convex.
This too is rather  easy: given a compact subset $K\subset\subset D$ and a boundary point $a\in \partial D$, consideration of $\frac{1}{z-a}$ shows that the holomorphically convex hull $\hat {K}=\hat {K}_D$ cannot approach $\partial D$ and consideration of the holomorphic function $z$ shows that $\hat {K}$ is bounded.
Since $\hat {K}$ is closed in $D$ these considerations prove that  $\hat {K}$ is compact.

**NB** Actually a) above is an equivalence: a domain $D\subset \mathbb C^n$ is  holomorphically convex iff it is  a domain of holomorphy.
This result was proved by Cartan-Thullen  in 1932. [Here](http://owpdb.mfo.de/detail?photo_id=12444) are the authors reunited 55 years later.

Answer (score 1):

A nonrigorous but perhaps more accessible answer: the way one constructs a function holomorphic on $D$ but not any larger open set is to construct a meromorphic function on $\Bbb C$ that has poles surrounding the boundary of $D$, so closely that they cut off any analytic continuation. Such a meromorphic function can be chosen to be the reciprocal of a holomorphic function with prescribed zeros; the existence of such functions is, as Daniel Fischer suggested, guaranteed by the [Weierstrass product theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassProductTheorem.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response.Regards,